# Чи є питомими подвійні слова "жив-був", "хороший-прехороший" тощо?

Tags: стилістика

[image: Дід Панас]

У «Вечірній казці діда Панаса» актор Петро Вескляров починає казку так:

> *В одному лісі **жили собі та були собі** Їжак із Їжачихою* — [YouTube відео](https://youtu.be/MxDQcUTUwcM?t=2m30s)

Той же актор Вескляров наприкінці передачі часто прощався з глядачами так:

> *Нехай вам присняться **хороші-прехороші**, **солодкі-пресолодкі** сни* — [YouTube відео](https://youtu.be/lwVMsA5IUoQ)

Відомо, що таке подвоєння часто вживається у російській: усі оці *жить-поживать, жив-здоров, путь-дорожка, такой-сякой* і багато інших. Тому виникає підозра, чи не є таке подвоєння наслідком порівняно недавнього негативного впливу іноземної мови.

Запитання полягає у тому, **наскільки питомим є подібне подвоєння саме для української мови?**
Чесно кажучи, я навіть ключових слів не можу придумати, щоб поґуґлити наукові джерела.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На мою думку, приклади в запитанні більше тяжіють до іншого(их) стилістичного(их) прийому(ів), аніж до *асиндетону*.

Наразі між мовознавцями немає консенсусу щодо того,

це [плеоназм](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC),

> **Плеона́зм** (від грец. πλεονασμός — надлишок, надмірність) — надлишковість засобів, що використовуються для передачі лексичного чи
>   граматичного змісту висловлювання. Плеоназм як властивість тексту є
>   протилежністю еліпсису і виявляє себе у повторенні чи синонімічному
>   дублюванні лексем (лексичний плеоназм) або граматичних форм
>   (граматичний плеоназм), а також у надто багатослівній передачі змісту,
>   який може бути висловлено коротше. Плеоназм може реалізовуватись і в
>   межах речення, і у ширшому контексті: цілі речення можуть практично
>   дублювати той самий зміст.,

чи [тавтологія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)),

> **Тавтологія** (дав.-гр. ταυτολογία від дав.-гр. ταυτο — те ж саме та дав.-гр. λόγος — мова) — у риториці, використання повторювання або
>   надлишковості у мові, коли одна частина висловлювання повністю або
>   частково дублює зміст іншої.

чи їх поєднання, та й різниця між поняттями досить нечітка.

Наприклад, А.А. Сагаровський у роботі [Плеоназм і тавтологія](http://www-philology.univer.kharkov.ua/katedras/prof_sites/sagarovsky/Sagarovs%27kyj_A_A_Pleonazm_i_tavtologija.pdf) називає тавтологію різновидом плеоназму.

> **`Плеоназм`** – словосполучення, у складі якого є зайві, однозначні слова чи вирази.
>
> **`Тавтологія`** – різновид плеоназму, що характеризується повторенням того самого тими чи іншими словами зі спільним коренем.
>
> Ці фігури нерідко вживаються як художньо-стилістичний засіб: (*каже –
>   промовляє, плакати – ридати, хлопці – молодці; рано – раненько, з діда
>   – прадіда, вік вікувати*)...

А от Караман С. О.  у [Сучасна українська літературна мова](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=6256) вважає тавтологію і плеоназм різними стилістичними фігурами

> Однак тавтологія (повтор) часто використовується письменниками в
>   художній літературі як стилістичний прийом підсилення значення одного
>   слова його слово­ твірним варіантом. Це повертає слову його первісну
>   образність, збагачує вислів додатковими нюансами — змістовими й
>   експресивними. Наприклад: *Щось шепотом шепоче, щось шумом шумить,
>   щось плаче над вбитим селом* (М. Черемшина).
>
> Тавтологія в художньому тексті рідко виступає у чистому вигляді,
>   частіше вона поєднується з іншими засобами виразності — синонімами,
>   анафорою (єдинопочатком), епіфорою (повторенням однакових слів,
>   звукосполучень наприкінці віршованих рядків), створюючи образи
>   потрібного авторові спрямування.
>
> У народних думах, казках, піснях, прислів’ях і приказках тавтологія
>   може поєднуватися з іншою сти­лістичною фігурою — плеоназмом. Це
>   нагромадження синонімічних слів, у тому числі спільнокореневих.
>   Наприклад: к*вилить-проквиляє, клене-проклинас, кличе-викликає*.

В. В. Шиприкевич у дослідженні [Що таке плеоназми?](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine9-6.pdf) розвиває думку, що, з-поміж іншого, стилістичну функцію виконують і "синонімічні однорідні слова
прикладкового типу", якщо це стосується іменникових утворень, як то: *кінця-краю, путь-доріженька, жалібниці-мрії* тощо, а також повтори, тобто тавтологія (і для інших частин мови), до прикладу: *прозорі-прозорі, ніжні-ніжні, світ світає* і подібні.

Слід зазначити, що більшість вчених відносять до джерел названих вище прийомів авторську творчість і фольклор (народні пісні, фразеологізми, прислів'я та приказки), зауважуючи, що ці стилістичні фігури "надають здебільшого художньому, інколи й публіцистичному стилю образності, яскравості, колориту".

Answer (score 8):

Це [асиндетони](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD) — безсполучникове поєднання слів (іменників, прикметників, дієслів, займенників, прислівників): *думи-бджоли, гори-хвилі, зорі-вівці, мед-вино, жито-пшениця, рута-м’ята, нічка-петрівочка, журба-горе, турки-яничари, Січ-мати, місяць-підкова, ворожка-ніч, криниці-ночі, терни-байраки, горе-біда; чужа-чужанина, піший-піхотинець; шити-білити, плакала-ридала; сякі-такі, сього-того; тяжко-важко, косо-криво*
(Зубков, "Українська мова: Універсальний довідник", Х., 2006, с. 139).

Comment: Узагалі, в статті [асиндетон](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Асиндетон) мова, НМД, дещо про інше. Тобто, НМД, не зовсім правильно взагалі самі такі подвійні слова називати асиндетонами, асиндетон — це радше саме явище (причому значно ширше, ніж лише такі «слова-слова»; мова про пропущення сполучників у реченні взагалі, на противагу [полісиндетону](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Полісиндетон) — їхній збільшеній кількості), а не самі слова (англійською іноді називають asyndet**ism**, а укр. — безсполучников**ість**, — НМД, ці терміни краще підкреслюють, що це саме явище, а не конкретні слова).

Comment: Крім того, на мою думку, не всі наведені в тесті запитання складні слова є результатом асиндетону. Якщо щодо «жили-поживали» і «живі-здорові» я цілком згоден (справді, це виглядає варіантом для «жили [cобі] та поживали [собі]» або «живі й здорові»), то от «хороший-прехороший» не виглядає скороченням від якоїсь конструкції зі сполучниками («хороший і прехороший», «хороший, але прехороший», «хороший чи прехороший», абощо). Відповідно, це вже складний прикметник зовсім іншої природи, НМД.

Comment: Щодо обіцянки-цяцянки… Якщо між ними тире — «Обіцянка — цяцянка, а дурневі радість» — то це просто підмет і присудок («обіцянка **є** незначущою іграшкою»). Але якщо між ними дефіс — «Мені вже набридли твої обіцянки-цяцянки» — тобто, пам'ятаючи відому приказку, мовець відразу додає до слова «обіцянка» [прикладку](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Прикладка), що характеризує відношення мовця до обіцянки співрозмовника — то, мені здається, це більше нагадує 4-й і 5-й рядки з тієї ж ст. 139 підручника (прикладка у постпозиції або така, що може мінятися з основним словом місцями), а не останній (асиндетон).

Comment: @Sasha, підтримую, це не зовсім *асиндетон*. Приклади в запитанні, НМД, тяжіють до іншого(их) стилістичного(их) прийому(ів). Наразі між мовознавцями немає консенсусу щодо того, це [плеоназм](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC), чи [тавтологія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)), чи їх поєднання), та й різниця між поняттями досить нечітка. Утім за наведеними в наступному коментарі лінками можна побачити приклади на підтвердження версії.

Comment: 1 [Тавтологія](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=6256), 2 [Плеоназм і тавтологія](http://www-philology.univer.kharkov.ua/katedras/prof_sites/sagarovsky/Sagarovs%27kyj_A_A_Pleonazm_i_tavtologija.pdf),3 [Що таке плеоназми?](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine9-6.pdf), 4 [Тавтологія як стилістична фігура: приклади](http://l-ponomar.com/tavtologiya-yak-stylistychnyj-zasib-pryklady/).

Comment: У «3» ці слова називають так: «**синонімічні однорідні слова прикладкового типу**». (Цікаво, що в деяких джерелах, наприклад, «4» чи [«5»](http://tverdyna.ucoz.ua/blog/v_jacheslav_vasilchenko_pro_kulturu_movi/2015-04-08-30-987), посилаючись на «Стилістику сучасної української мови» Пономарева, взагалі зводять *все поняття тавтології до повторення саме однокореневих слів*, що для мене якось дивно.)

Comment: Друзі, велике прохання. Не ображайтеся, ваш контент цікавий, але коментарі потрібні для уточнення запитань та відповідей. Вони не призначені для спроб надавати свої відповіді (повні чи часткові). І, тим більше, не для привернення чиєїсь уваги. В ідеалі, кінцевою метою коментарів є покращення Q/A дописів із подальшою втратою актуальності коментаря і його наступним **видаленням**. Саме цим наш формат відрізняється від формату чат-бордів. Тому будь ласка, намагайтеся оформлювати свої відповіді (навіть часткові) у виді, власне, відповідей.

Comment: @bytebuster, жодних образ. Здається, завжди й намагаємось так робити - "оформлювати свої відповіді (навіть часткові) у виді, власне, відповідей". Щоправда, не завжди одразу є час на оформлення повноцінної відповіді, та й відповідь має "достигнути", тому для початку коментар, щоб привернути увагу.

Answer (score 5):

Деякі джерела вельми не рекомендують вживати *жив-був*. А щодо иншого: *хороші-прехороші, солодкі-пресолодкі*, то се все инша пісня: там просте підсилення і близьке за значенням до [патосу](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%81) чи [гіперболи](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_(%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)), чого не сказати про: *жить-поживать, жив-здоров, путь-дорожка, такой-сякой*.

> <sup>[Довідник з українського слововживання «Неправильно — правильно»](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/dieslova) • Марія Волощак</sup>
>   Жив-був ― Жив-поживав (жив собі)

---

> <sup>[«Як ми говоримо»,  сторінка 92](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/zhyty-buty-zhyty-sobi-zhyty-pozhyvaty) • [Борис Антоненко-Давидович](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)</sup>
>   **§ 13 Жити-бути, жити собi, жити-поживати**
>
> „*Жив-був* дiд та баба“, — чуємо початок казки в радiопередачах, а то
>   читаємо i в дитячих книжках. Але такий вислiв є характернiшим для росiйських народних казок: „*Жил-был* старик со старухой“; українська народна казка з дiда-прадiда починалась висловом *жити собi*: „*Жив собi* дiд та баба, була в них курочка ряба“ (казка) або *жити-пoживати*: „*Жив-поживав* козак заможний Клим“ (Л. Глiбов).
>
> Вислiв *жити-бути* трапляється в художнiй лiтературi („*Жила-була* в гаю
>   сорока“. — Л. Глiбов), але не слiд замiняти ним усi iншi українськi народнi вислови, а тим бiльше вiдкидати їх.

---

> <sup>[«Походження українців, росіян, білорусів та їхніх мов»](http://litopys.org.ua/pivtorak/pivt06.htm) • [Григорій Петрович Півторак](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)</sup>
>   Крім цього, впливом **фінського субстрату** дослідники пояснюють також чимало
>   специфічних особливостей російської мови, таких як:
>
> - наявність акання й редукції голосних в усному мовленні,
> - парні слова типу *стежки-дорожки, руки-ноги, жив-здоров, такой-сякой, нежданно-негаданно, есть-пить* та ін.,
> - мовний зворот *у меня есть* (замість більш характерного для слов'янських мов звороту *я маю*),
> - фразеологічні вирази ***жил-был***, житье-бытье, жить-поживать, как можется?, как живете-можете?,
> - запозичені з фінських мов лексеми *ковылять, колеть (околеть), Мóсква* та ін.

Comment: Не знаю, чи звернули увагу, стосовно займенника *собі* й подібних гарно, як на мене, пояснює В. В. Шиприкевич у роботі [Що таке плеоназми?](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine9-6.pdf) - c. 4, абзаци 2-3.